# Running KVM in KVM with a Windows 2012 guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a VPS running on KVM but my hoster doesn't support Windows 2012 yet. For some applications (Signalr) I need W2012.

What would be the impact of running Centos6 as the primary guest (KVM host) with KVM installed which hosts Windows 2012 again?

Would there be terrible performance losses or other culprits?

Comment: if you are just screwing around with signlR you could do the following its free for 90 days. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clemensv/archive/2012/02/13/signalr-powered-by-service-bus.aspx but be careful with azure its kinda addicting..

Comment: I know but it will be for a production environment. But the problem is that the EU bandwidth is just too costly.

Comment: Find a provider that _does_ support what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do nested virtualization within EL6, the KVM kernel modules do not support it.

You *could* run e.g. a Fedora KVM host, then run Windows within that provided you have the [appropriate hardware support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_Virtualization_Indexing):

http://kashyapc.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/nested-virtualization-with-kvm-intel/

however [research indicates](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-bbfinkel/turtles_paper.pdf) that the performance within the Windows guest would be seriously degraded, and Fedora is not exactly reliable enough for long-term production deployment. Not recommended.